# Can't pass formatting to javascript

Tags: javascript, formatting

I have a question regarding reading a webpage then printing a pop up copy.

Basically I have a form on page A.  If the user elects to pay by check, their invoice will popup in a new window B which is a print preview.  The invoice table found on A is well formatted.  Unfortunately in the pop up print page B, the table formatting (in fact all the page formatting) is gone.  Namely, the centring of the first column and right justifying of the 2nd, row shading, and table border.

I was thinking of creating 3 divs; one before, one after and one including the table invoice, but all my attempts give a misformatted table.  Then I thought I'd rewrite using divs in the page A, and rewriting the popup printer page to reflect this (multiple strings getting written as strHeader, strTable, strFooter).  Any thoughts on how best to proceed?

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printContent(id){
str=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
newwin=window.open('','printwin','left=100,top=100,width=1000%,height=1000%')
newwin.document.write('<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n')
newwin.document.write('<TITLE>Print Page</TITLE>\n')
newwin.document.write('<script>\n')
newwin.document.write('function chkstate(){\n')
newwin.document.write('if(document.readyState=="complete"){\n')
newwin.document.write('window.close()\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('else{\n')
newwin.document.write('setTimeout("chkstate()",2000)\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('function print_win(){\n')
newwin.document.write('window.print();\n')
newwin.document.write('chkstate();\n')
newwin.document.write('}\n')
newwin.document.write('<\/script>\n')
newwin.document.write('</HEAD>\n')
newwin.document.write('<BODY onload="print_win()">\n')

newwin.document.write("<b><font size= '6' >" + 'Event Registration' + "   </font></b>")
newwin.document.write(str)
newwin.document.write('footer info goes here')

newwin.document.write('</BODY>\n')
newwin.document.write('</HTML>\n')
newwin.document.close()
}
</script>

<?php $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Event Registration Payment')?> 
<?php if($eventRegistration['EventRegistration']['payment_type'] =="cheque"):?>
<b>To pay by cheque...</b><a href="#null" onclick="printContent('print_div1')"> click here</a>
<?php endif;?>

<DIV id="print_div1" style="border:1px solid #000000">

<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
<?php echo $this->requestAction('/liveEditRegions/getRegion/60'); ?>

<table class="invoiceTable" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
<tr class="titleRow">
<th class="center">Item</th>
<th class="center">Price</th>
</tr>

<!-------------------------------------registration-->
<?php if($registrationPrice > 0):?> 
<tr>
    <th class="center">Registration Price</th>
    <td class="right">$<?php echo number_format($registrationPrice, 2) ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif;?>

<!-------------------------------------------events-->
<?php if($eventRegistration['EventRegistration']['dinner_ticket_number'] > 0):?> 
<tr>
    <th class="center">Dinner Ticket(s) x <?php echo     $eventRegistration['EventRegistration']['dinner_ticket_number']?> @ $<?php echo number_format($eventRegistration['EventRegistration']['dinner_ticket_price'])?></th>
    <td class="right">$<?php echo number_format($dinnerticketTotal, 2) ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif;?> 

<?php if($eventRegistration['EventRegistration']['student_social_ticket_number'] > 0):?> 
<tr>
    <th class="center">Student Social Ticket(s) x <?php echo $eventRegistration['EventRegistration']['student_social_ticket_number']?> @ $<?php echo number_format($eventRegistration['EventRegistration']['student_social_ticket_price'])?></th>
    <td class="right">$<?php echo number_format($ssticketTotal, 2) ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif;?> 

<tr>
<th class="right">Sub total</th>
<td class="right">$<?php echo number_format($subtotal, 2); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="right">TAX</th>
<td class="right">$<?php echo number_format($tax, 2); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="right">Total</th>
<td class="right">$<?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-----------------------------------------CHOOSE PAYMENT-->
<?php if($eventRegistration['EventRegistration']['payment_type'] =="credit card"):?>

[snip]

<?php endif;?>

<?php if($eventRegistration['EventRegistration']['payment_type'] =="cheque"):?>
<?php endif;?>
</DIV>
```

Comment: To the user who down-voted: you are wrong.  I did plenty of research which is what brought me here.  If you have constructive criticism, kindly suggest search terms or duplicate enquiries.  I feel it is quite clear, the coding is included and well-commented.  It is obviously useful, at the very least to me.  I can't believe this would have no future use to others.

Comment: I have another solution which is inelegant; basically I can read in the table variables then recreate the table in js manually.  This will be a pain though and it seems there ought to be a better way.

Comment: I tried reading in the page, parsing by sections, then replacing the table formatting elements (e.g. "center" -> "right") but it seems to make no difference on the final format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try seeing if there is a css stylesheet overiding your change.  Maybe explicitly create a table style on the new page to double check.